# Get XML data with random Id nodes

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I would like to read a specific node of my XML but I am having problems on how to focus the problem.

Right now the XML file has this structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Assessment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns="http://www1.macadam.eu/Webservices/FleetCarV3/">
 <Damages>
 <Damage>
  <Id>15724669</Id>
  <AssessmentId>1959065</AssessmentId>
  <Location>
   <Id>5</Id>
    <DescriptionEN>Panel R R</DescriptionEN>
    <DescriptionNL>Panneel A R</DescriptionNL>
    <DescriptionFR>Panneau ARD</DescriptionFR>
    <DescriptionDE>Panel HR</DescriptionDE>
    <DescriptionES>Panel TRAS DR</DescriptionES>
  </Location>
  <Type>
    <Id>1274</Id>
    <DescriptionEN>Bump(s)</DescriptionEN>
    <DescriptionNL>Deuk(en)</DescriptionNL>
    <DescriptionFR>Bosse(s)</DescriptionFR>
    <DescriptionDE>Dell(en)</DescriptionDE>
    <DescriptionES>Abolladuras</DescriptionES>
  </Type>
  <Repair>
    <Id>1307</Id>
    <DescriptionEN>Le - Replace and paint</DescriptionEN>
    <DescriptionNL>Le - Vervangen en spuiten</DescriptionNL>
    <DescriptionFR>Le - Remplacer et peindre</DescriptionFR>
    <DescriptionDE>Erneuern + lackieren</DescriptionDE>
    <DescriptionES>Le - Reemplazar Y Pintar</DescriptionES>
  </Repair>
  <Comment />
 </Damage>
 <Damage>
   ...
   ...
 </Damage>
 <Damage>
   ...
   ...
 </Damage>
 </Damages>
</Assessment>
```

Note that I put more `<Damage>` tags. Each `<Id>` is different per `<Damage>` node, and what I need is the text inside `<DescriptionES>` nodes.

Below is code trying to get the `<Location>` node:

```vb
nsmgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(m_xmld.NameTable)
nsmgr.AddNamespace("sd", "http://www1.macadam.eu/Webservices/FleetCarV3/")

m_nodelist = m_xmld.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/sd:Assessment/sd:Damages/sd:Damage/sd:Location", nsmgr)
For Each m_node In m_nodelist
    For j = 0 To 5000
        Dim Location = m_node.SelectSingleNode("/sd:Assessment/sd:Damages/sd:Damage/sd:Location[sd:Id=" & j & "]", nsmgr).InnerText
        If Location IsNot Nothing Then
            MsgBox("i'm in")
            'txtDamageReport.Text = Location
        End If
    Next j
Next
```

It does not work, as expected. I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to target a specific node. Do you want to get all Location of all Damage ?

Comment: @chateaur it was a test to see if I can access to <Location>. I need all <Damage>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML which have little bid easy to understand API and better readability

```vb
Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Load(pathToTheFile)
Dim ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www1.macadam.eu/Webservices/FleetCarV3/")

For Each damage As XElement in document.Descendants(ns + "Damage")
    Dim damageId = damage.Element(ns + "Id").Value
    Dim locationDescription = damage.Element(ns + "Location").
                                     Element(ns + "DescriptionES").
                                     Value

    MessageBox.Show($"Id = {damageId};  Desc = {locationDescription}")
Next
```

vb.net have possibility to use [XML Axis Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384974.aspx), which can be useful if you have a schema for the xml files, then you will get IntelliSense support for element names.
Same code as above by using Axis properties.
For using axis properties with namespace you need import namespace to the file

```vb
Imports <xmlns:ns="http://www1.macadam.eu/Webservices/FleetCarV3/">  

For Each damage As XElement in document...<ns:Damage>
    Dim damageId = damage.<ns:Id>.Value
    Dim locationDescription = damage.<ns:Location>.<ns:DescriptionES>.Value

    MessageBox.Show($"Id = {damageId};  Desc = {locationDescription}")
Next
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using your code but it does not show any popup (both already tried). It seems very clear and logical code but is not showing the data. It's a bit strange.

Comment: You need proved a namespace too, check my updated answer

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm now. Thank you so much for your solution and for your micro-tutorial of LINQ and Xml Properties. I will use it in the future, sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VB XmlDocument as follows. I believe that the XmlNamespaceManager is wrong in your code but since you didn't provide it ...

This works for me :

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument

doc.Load(path)

//Add a namespace to all the document
Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("g", "http://www1.macadam.eu/Webservices/FleetCarV3/")

Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList
Dim root As XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//g:Assessment//g:Damages//g:Damage//g:Location", nsmgr)

// Loop over damage section
For Each damageNode As XmlNode In nodeList
     Dim id As String = damageNode.SelectSingleNode("//g:Id", nsmgr).InnerText
     Dim desc As String = damageNode.SelectSingleNode("//g:DescriptionES", nsmgr).InnerText

      MsgBox(id & vbCrLf & desc)
Next
```

Comment: Namespace added! In my case, your code gets data but different than <Damage> section. The problem is that this is a ~3k lines XML, so I suppose it has some troubles getting data. Maybe it's a good idea to show the full XML content.